# from pygtk_image import * ERROR

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I am new to python and I have question, please. I have python 2.7.3 and I have installed gtk to make GUI. I found a code and I want to test it but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module> 
from pygtk_image import *
ImportError: No module named pygtk_image
```

what does this mean? I searched in the internet about how to install pygtk_image, but I did not find a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you install pygtk

Comment: No, I just installed gtk.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't downloaded all necessary modules for your code.

Try this:
https://github.com/jayrambhia/SimpleCVexamples/blob/master/pygtk_image/pygtk_image.py

Maybe it is the module you are missing.

Comment: I tried that code, and it worked without errors  But  i did not see any outputs. I mean nothing appeared in the screen